# Android sdk won't allow download api 8 and 10

Tags: android, sdk

[image]

The android sdk won't allow me to install api8 and api10 because there isn't an option to down load the sdk platform. Is there any ways to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try in your SDK manager Packages->Reload
2. Uninstall the SDK from ADD/Remove programs. Delete the .Android directory in your Users directory. Reinstall the SDK from scratch.